# Syntax error near "=>" when running pg_upgrade 9.4 to 9.5

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, pg-upgrade

I am unable to upgrade my postgresql server from 9.4 to 9.5 due to the following error message:

```
pg_restore: creating OPERATOR "public.->"
pg_restore: creating OPERATOR "public.<@"
pg_restore: creating OPERATOR "public.=>"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 1617; 2617 17937 OPERATOR => william
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "=>"
LINE 1: CREATE OPERATOR => (
                        ^
    Command was: CREATE OPERATOR => (
    PROCEDURE = "tconvert",
    LEFTARG = "text",
    RIGHTARG = "text"
);
```

I have not been able to find anything relevant by googling. The most relevant thing I can find is someone who encountered this issue with a much older version of hstore, and the fix is not clear.

I am using homebrew on a Mac. I would work around the issue with pg_dumpall, but I can no longer run that because the 9.4 binaries are loading the libs for 9.5 following the upgrade. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It looks like `"public.=>"` should probably be `"public"."=>"` . (and mixing versions is generally not a good idea)

Comment: Yeah but I didn't create it, it is just part of the hstore extension I am using. I am not mixing versions, I am just trying to upgrade my old data from 9.4 to 9.5. The only reason I am trying to run 9.4 now that 9.5 is installed is to try other methods of migrating my data. I want to do this on the production server, so I need to find a viable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solutions either were not options, or they didn't work.
The solution that worked for me was:

```
ALTER EXTENSION hstore UPDATE TO '1.1';
```

*Source: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/22170.1457479307%40sss.pgh.pa.us*

Answer (score 1):

This is expected, see the [release notes for PostgreSQL 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-5.html#AEN127021):

> - Allow `=>` to specify named parameters in function calls (Pavel Stehule)
>
>   Previously only `:=` could be used. This requires removing the possibility for `=>` to be a user-defined operator. Creation of user-defined `=>` operators has been issuing warnings since PostgreSQL 9.0.

You'll have to use a different name for the operator. There is no workaround short of hacking up PostgreSQL.

It might be that your problem is an old installation of the `hstore` contrib module that was never migrated to an extension. In that case you can try to upgrade it *in the old database* **before** exporting like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore FROM unpackaged;
```

That would get rid of the `=>` operator that has been deprecated for a long time. You'd have to change all application code that relies on it.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't create the operator, and I don't use it in any of my procedures. I don't understand where it came from or how to remove it, I just want to upgrade my database. Everything I have ever installed is totally "out of the box". :(

Comment: No, there is no operator `public.=>` in core PostgreSQL. In case it is a leftover from an old `hstore` installation, I've amended my answer to address that case.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a different error: "ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist"

I got my upgrade to work by reverting to the old version and using pg_dumpall.

Comment: Well, the old `public.=>` will also not be created with this method.

Comment: Again, I was not using it. I just want my hstore in 9.5 to be completely vanilla and current.

Comment: Then you'll have to manually remove the cruft that's there in the old installation and `CREATE EXTENSION hstore`. The extension can be upgraded without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, but in the end I reverted to the previous version and used pg_dumpall to backup my databases and reload them in the new version, completely forgetting about carrying over defunct operators. In homebrew this was as simple as changing a symlink:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
rm postgresql
ln -sv ../../Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/lib/postgresql .
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start # start old cluster
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/bin/pg_dumpall > backup.sql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile stop # stop old cluster
rm postgresql
ln -sv ../../Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3/lib/postgresql .
```

The rest of the upgrade process I take from https://kkob.us/2016/01/09/homebrew-and-postgresql-9-5/

Loading the data is just `psql < backup.sql` No hstore errors this time!